# Travis: Compilation error on lombok generated methods

Tags: java, travis-ci, lombok

I am trying to add CI to my current Spring boot project.
I added a build on Travis.
It always fails on compilation errors on methods generated by Lombok.
Is there something that I am missing ?
I have been stuck on this for more than a week.
I am setting it up on this branch https://github.com/madicorp/smartinvestplus-back/tree/travis
Travis job: https://travis-ci.org/madicorp/smartinvestplus-back

EDIT:
My travis config

```
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
env:
  - MVN_VERSION=3.3.9
cache:
    directories:
        - $HOME/.m2
install: eval mvn clean install -DskipTests=true -B -V
script: eval mvn clean install
notifications:
  webhooks:
    on_success: change  # options: [always|never|change] default: always
    on_failure: always  # options: [always|never|change] default: always
    on_start: false     # default: false
```

Get these typse of compilation error for all the methods generated by lombok in my POJOs

```
  symbol:   method isGenerated()
  location: variable closeRate of type  net.madicorp.smartinvestplus.stockexchange.domain.CloseRate
  [ERROR] diagnostic: /home/travis/build/madicorp/smartinvestplus-back/src/main/java/net/madicorp/smartinvestplus/stockexchange/service/CloseRateDivisionAdjuster.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
    adjustedCloseRate.setRate(closeRate.getRate());


  symbol:   method getRate()
  location: variable closeRate of type     net.madicorp.smartinvestplus.stockexchange.domain.CloseRate
 [ERROR] diagnostic: /home/travis/build/madicorp/smartinvestplus-back/src/main/java/net/madicorp/smartinvestplus/stockexchange/service/CloseRateDivisionAdjuster.java:32: error: invalid method reference
             .map(Division::getRate)
```

Comment: I will be helpful if you post the compilation error stacktrace

Comment: Have a look at the travis job, at the end there is the compilation error

Comment: Have you tries using delombok plugin for maven?

Comment: I will try to when I get home but do you have any explanation about why it doesn't work ? I already used successfully Lombok on Mac and Windows, when I decompile classes generated methods are there, and I would really like to understand why it doesn't work on travis environment. Because using delombok seems a workaround and adds another step to my build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was finally due to a filename/class case mismatch on my main spring boot class when scaffolding the project with JHipster.
I spotted the problem on an Ubuntu VM as I was working on MacOS.
The latter does not care and compile the project successfully while the former rightfully fails on this one. I had to commit a rename of the file and all the other problems just vanished.
In the end, they were just side effects of compilation failure on main spring boot class.
Thx @noscreenname for your help.

Comment: Doesn't look like I was of much help, but I'm glad you found the cause of the problem.

Comment: But this was because I misled you, and myself, with these lombok errors :) There were so many compilation errors that it was hard to list them all in a question. That's why I tried to find the most significant and unfortunately missed the root one. However, thanks for taking the time to help me, I really appreciate, even though the question was downvoted :).